# Possible to collapse and expand in ractivejs?

Tags: ractivejs

Looking at [example](http://webcloud.se/jQuery-Collapse/)

HTML

```
 <ul>
    <li>Blueberry</li>
    <li>Raspberry</li>
    <li>Pear</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Banana</li>
    <li>Cherry</li>
    <li>Mango</li>
    <li>Soursop</li>
    </ul>
```

Thinking whether it is possible this way in ractivejs

Like this:

```
<ul>
  {{#each fruit:i}}
   {{#if count > 4}}
    <a href="#" class="less">Show less</a>
   {{else}}
   <li>{{fruit.name}}</li>
   <a href="#" class="more">Show more</a>
   {{/if}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

If got more items, it would limit only 4 items and display "Show more". Then click on show less after display all item and it will collapse.

Wonder if that is possible? Also would css animation work for class: more and less instead of on-click handlers to expand and collapse? (similar to slide up and down).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Collapse and expand is merely tracking who is active, and adding the proper `display` style to those who are. That can be done with plain templating (see upper half of code).

The "show more" can be done in 2 ways:

- If you load your data dynamically (via ajax) per load more, then you can just `concat` to your existing `fruits` array and use that for iteration.
- If your data is already there (you loaded all fruits, yet only want to show a few at a time), you can use a property to track the number of currently displayed, and a computed property to slice the fruits array using that number. Clicking load more will increase that number (say 4 to 8), kicking the computed prop to recalculate using 8 this time.

Here's an example:

```
<ul>
  {{#each slicedFruits:index}}
    <li>
      <!-- Here, clicking the header sets the current fruit to display -->
      <h4 on-click="set('currentFruitIndex', index)">{{name}}</h4>
      <!-- Here, we conditionally apply block or none depending on who's showing -->
      <div style="display:{{if currentFruitIndex === index}}block{{else}}none{{/if}};">{{details}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
  <!-- using the built-in `add`, we add 4 to `displayedFruits` -->
  <a href="#" on-click="add('displayedFruits', 4)>Load More</a>
</ul>

<script>
component.exports = {
  data : {
    fruits: [],            // load up your fruits here
    currentFruitIndex: -1, // change this to any default, -1 for nothing
    displayedFruits: 4,    // change to how many you liked displayed first
  },
  computed: {
    // We slice the main array `fruits` by `displayedFruits`.
    // Changing `displayedFruits` will recalculate this and update the template
    slicedFruits: function(){
      return this.get('fruits').slice(0, this.get('displayedFruits'));
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

As for animation, you can check out Transistions. [There's a good example of accordion here](https://ractivejs.github.io/ractive-transitions-slide/).